When solving $\sin{x}+\cos{x}=\sin{2x}+\cos{2x}$, where does the extra solution come from?
Background
This question is from the 1907 Victorian Universities and Schools Examination Board Trigonometry (Senior) Examination.
My solution is given below, but apparently there is an extra solution that I have missed and I cannot see where.
The problem
Find all solutions to $\sin{x}+\cos{x}=\sin{2x}+\cos{2x}$.
My solution
$\sin{2x}-\sin{x}+\cos{2x}-\cos{x}=0$
$2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\cos{\frac{3x}{2}}-2\sin{\frac{3x}{2}}\sin{\frac{x}{2}}=0$
So either $\sin{\frac{x}{2}}=0$ or $\tan{\frac{3x}{2}}=1$
This gives me the solutions $x=2k\pi,x=\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi,x=\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi$ where $k$ is an integer.
However, apparently $x=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is also a solution.
Can anyone help me see what I have missed?

$\tan x$ has period $\pi$, so $\tan(3x/2)$ has period $2\pi/3$. Or, if you insist on using $2k\pi$ for grouping, you get three families of solutions to $\tan(3x/2)=A$.

Dou you mean $tan3x/2=1$?

Yes, thanks I did. Will fix now.

@JyrkiLahtonen ah, yes, very good point. I don't really care which grouping is used, I was just concerned I had missed a solution somehow.

Or, $\tan(3y/2)=1$ if and only if $3y/2=\pi/4+k\pi$ if and only if $y=\pi/6+2k\pi/3.$

From the comments, $\tan{\dfrac{3x}{2}}=1$ if and only if
$\dfrac{3x}{2} = \dfrac\pi4 + m\pi$ for some integer $m,$
which in turn is true if and only if
$x = \dfrac\pi6 + \dfrac{2m}{3}\pi$ for some integer $m.$
Consider three cases:
Case $m \equiv 0 \pmod 3$: Then $x = \dfrac\pi6 + 2k\pi$ for some integer $k.$
Case $m \equiv 1 \pmod 3$: Then
$x = \dfrac\pi6 + 2k\pi + \dfrac23\pi = \dfrac56\pi + 2k\pi$ for some integer $k.$
Case $m \equiv 2 \pmod 3$: Then
$x = \dfrac\pi6 + 2n\pi + \dfrac43\pi = 2n\pi + \dfrac32\pi
 = 2(n+1)\pi - \dfrac\pi2$ for some integer $n.$
Equivalently, substituting $k$ for $n+1,$ we have
$x = 2k\pi - \dfrac\pi2$ for some integer $k.$
The third case is your missing solution.

Starting with OP’s solution, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \quad  2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{3 x}{2}-2 \sin \frac{3 x}{2} \sin \frac{x}{2}=0 \\
& \Rightarrow 2 \sin \frac{x}{2}\left(\cos \frac{3 x}{2}-\sin \frac{3 x}{2}\right)=0 \\
& \Leftrightarrow \sin \frac{x}{2}=0 \text { or } \cos \frac{3 x}{2}=\sin \frac{3 x}{2} \\
& \Leftrightarrow \frac{x}{2}=n \pi \text { or } \tan \frac{3 x}{2}=1 \\
& \Leftrightarrow x=2 n \pi \text { or } \frac{3 x}{2}=n \pi+\frac{\pi}{4} \\
& \Leftrightarrow x=2 n \pi \text { or } \frac{\pi}{6}(4 n+1),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$
Alternatively
$$
\begin{array}{ll} 
& \sin x+\cos x=\sin 2 x+\cos 2 x \\
\Leftrightarrow & \sqrt{2} \cos \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sqrt{2} \cos \left(2 x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
\Leftrightarrow & \cos \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos \left(2 x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
\Leftrightarrow & \quad 2 x-\frac{\pi}{4}=2 n \pi \pm\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
\Leftrightarrow & x=2 n \pi \text { or }\frac{\pi}{6}(4 n+1)
\end{array}
$$
where $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$

I make a point of not answering my own questions, but in this case, I have found my own error. I am not editing the question, as it will make the other (excellent) answers look out of place.
When I wrote $\tan{\frac{3x}{2}}=1$, I concluded that $\frac{3x}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}$ were the two angles to work with and neglected the option of $\frac{3x}{2}=\frac{-3\pi}{4}$.
So the solution $x=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is indeed valid.
